# How to create table with jQuery JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table, jsonp

Can somebody help me to figure out how can I add tr row every time loop start. Below is my jQuery code:

```
var row = $("<tr></tr>");

     $.each(data.response.docs, function (i,  item) { // json is the name of the object

        row.append('<td>' + item.adServerId + '</td>'); //item is named at the opening of this $.each function
        row.append('<td>' + item.advertiserId + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.advertiserName + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.campaignId + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.campaignName + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.bookedImps + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.imps + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.clicks + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.ctr + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.postViewConvs + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.postViewConvsRate + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.convs + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.convsRate + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.targetRevenue + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.revenue + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.cost + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.startDate + '</td>');
        row.append('<td>' + item.endDate + '</td>,</tr>');
        $("#adcampaignGrid").append(row);
```

Comment: Please use `row.append($('<td>').text(whatever))` instead of concatenation, it helps avoid XSS and such and is just a better way to go about things generally.

Answer (score 2):

Move `var row = $('<tr></tr>')` inside the loop?

```
 $.each(data.response.docs, function (i,  item) { // json is the name of the object

     var row = $("<tr></tr>");
     // rest of your code
 }
```

Also, as @minitech noted, use `text()` to wrap `item.xxx` to avoid getting funny stuff injected into your page.

For headers, I'd suggest just putting your header directly on the html:

http://jsfiddle.net/QtnS4/1/

```
<table id="aa">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>       
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>​
```

JS:

```
var records = [
    {key: "Value 1", key2: "Value 1b"},
    {key: "Value 2", key2: "Value 2b"}
];

for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    row.append($('<td></td>').text(records[i].key));
    row.append($('<td></td>').text(records[i].key2));
    $('#aa').append(row);
}
```

Comment: Also how can I add th? I am trying to achieve this table format: `<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Advertiser</th>
    <th>Campaign</th>
    <th>Impressions Served</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Record 1</td>
      <td>Record 3</td>
      <td>Record 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Record 2</td>
      <td>Record 2</td>
      <td>Record 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>`

Comment: @ShoaibUd-Din for headers, just put it inside your html table directly instead of doing it from javascript, so your initial table would already have the header, all you do is just appending to tbody.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(data.response.docs, function (i, item) {
  var row = $("<tr></tr>");
  for (var i in item) row.append($('<td>').text(item[i]));
  $("#adcampaignGrid").append(row);
});
```

Or if there is no need in all keys:

```
$.each(data.response.docs, function (i, item) {
  var props = [
    'adServerId', 
    'advertiserId', 
    'advertiserName', 
    'campaignId', 
    'campaignName', 
    'bookedImps', 
    'imps', 
    'clicks', 
    'ctr', 
    'postViewConvs', 
    'postViewConvsRate', 
    'convs', 
    'convsRate', 
    'targetRevenue', 
    'revenue', 
    'cost', 
    'startDate', 
    'endDate'
  ];

  var row = $("<tr></tr>");
  for (var i in props) row.append($('<td>').text(item[props[i]]));
  $("#adcampaignGrid").append(row);
});
```

Comment: Also how can I add th? I am trying to achieve this table format: `<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Advertiser</th>
    <th>Campaign</th>
    <th>Impressions Served</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Record 1</td>
      <td>Record 3</td>
      <td>Record 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Record 2</td>
      <td>Record 2</td>
      <td>Record 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
`